# SQL Server Count Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have three tables as below:

```
Article
No  Storage_code   Type_code
--- ------------   ---------
1   10 00 00          S
2   10 10 00        P
1   10 10 10        S
3   11 00 00        C
1   10 00 00        C
2   11 10 10        P

Storage
Main_Code Division_Code Safe_Code Position_Code   Main_Name
--------- ------------- --------- ------------- -------------
10 00 00     10         00  00              Div1
10 10 00        10          10  00         Div1_Saf1
10 10 10     10         10  10         Div1_Saf1_Pos1
10 10 11        10          10  11              Div1_Saf1_Pos2
10 10 12        10          10  12         Div1_Saf1_Pos3
10 11 00        10          11  00         Div1_Saf2
10 11 10        10          11  10         Div1_Saf2_Pos1
10 11 11     10         11  11              Div1_Saf2_Pos2
10 11 12        10           11 12              Div1_Saf2_Pos3
11 00 00        11           00 00              Div2
11 10 00     11         10  00         Div2_Saf1
11 10 10        11          10  10         Div2_Saf1_Pos1
11 10 11        11          10  11         Div2_Saf1_Pos2
11 10 12        11          10  12         Div2_Saf1_Pos3
11 11 00        11          11  00         Div2_Saf2
11 11 10        11          11  10         Div2_Saf2_Pos1
11 11 11        11          11  11         Div2_Saf2_Pos2
11 11 12        11          11  12         Div2_Saf2_Pos3

Types
Code        Name
--------        --------
C       Cards
P       Plates
S       Stickers
```

and I want the result by one select as the follow:

```
Main_Code    Division_Code Safe_Code Position_Code Main_Name    Cards Plates Stickers Total
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10 00 00          10         00 00    Div1      1    1       2     4
10 10 00          10            10  00    Div1_Saf1 0    1      1      2
10 10 10          10            10  10    Div1_Saf1_Pos1    0    0      1      1
11 00 00          11            00  00    Div2      1    1      0      2
11 10 00          11            10  00    Div2_Saf1 0    1      0      1
11 10 10          11            10  10    Div2_Saf1_Pos1    0    1      0      1
```

Can any one help me plz as soon as possible.

Comment: I've *started* an edit on your question, so that we can see the tables. But I'm not going to do all the cleanup. When posting code or items that should have a fixed layout, please use the `{}` code sample button. And use the preview area so that you can *see* what your question will actually look like. The original question was unreadable.

Comment: You also need to explain how the `Cards`, `Plates` and `Stickers` columns are computed.

Comment: What you want is a pivot query. You can do this manually using case statements and aggregates or using the PIVOT clause. There are many, many of examples on this site that you can search for.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for pivoting the rows into columns, try this:

```
SELECT
  s.[Main_Code],
  s.Division_Code,
  s.Safe_Code,
  s.Position_Code,
  s.Main_Name,
  SUM(CASE WHEN t.Name ='Cards' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Cards, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN t.Name ='Plates' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Plates, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN t.Name ='Stickers' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Stickers,
  COUNT(t.Name) AS Total
FROM Storage s
INNER JOIN Article a ON a.Storage_code = s.[MainCode]
INNER JOIN Types   t ON a.Type_code = t.Code
GROUP BY s.Main_Code,
         s.Division_Code,
         s.Safe_Code,
         s.Position_Code,
         s.Main_Name;
```